# Diffeomorphism and bounds on Sobolev $H^1$ norms

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $U^{\prime}, V^{\prime} \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be open, bounded and $\Phi: U^{\prime} \rightarrow V^{\prime}$ be a diffeomorphism. Let $U \subset \subset U^{\prime}$ Then
$$
V:=\Phi(U) \subset \subset V^{\prime}
$$
is open.

How do I prove that there exists $C>0$ such that for any $u \in C^{\infty}(\bar{U})$ we have
$$
\frac{1}{C}\|v\|_{H^{1}(V)} \leq\|u\|_{H^{1}(U)} \leq C\|v\|_{H^{1}(V)}, \quad \text { for } v:=u \circ \Phi^{-1} .
$$

**My attempt:**

$\|u\|_{H^{1}}=\sqrt{\|u\|_{L^{2}}^{2}+\left\|u^{\prime}\right\|_{L^{2}}^{2}}$

I would show $\|v\|_{H^{1}}^{2} \leq C\|u\|_{H}^{2}$ by estimating $\|v\|_{L^{2}}$ by $C\|u\|_{L^{2}}$ and $\left\|v^{\prime}\right\|_{L^{2}}$ by $\left\|u^{\prime}\right\|_{L^{2}}$

I'm not sure how to use change of variables/chain rule to do this.

Comment: Can you write down the change of variable formula you have?

Comment: I don't have one. That's what I need help with.

Comment: See [here](https://math.mit.edu/~larsh/teaching/F2007/handouts/changeofvariables.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

$$\|v\|_{L^2(V)}^2 = \int_V |u(\Phi^{-1}(x))|^2dx = \int_{\Phi^{-1}(V)} |u(y)|^2 \lvert\det \nabla\Phi^{-1}(y)|dy \le C_1(\Phi)\|u\|_{L^2(U)}^2  $$
where $C_1(\Phi)=\lVert\det\nabla\Phi^{-1}\|_{C^0(\overline V)}<\infty$ because $\Phi$ is a diffeomorphism.
The derivative is similar:
\begin{align}\|\nabla v\|_{L^2}^2 &= \int_V |\nabla_x(u(\Phi^{-1}(x)))|^2dx\\&=\int_V |\nabla(\Phi^{-1})(x)(\nabla_y u)(\Phi^{-1}(x))|^2dx \\&\le C_2(\Phi)\int_V|(\nabla_y u)(\Phi^{-1}(x))|^2dx \\&\le C_1(\Phi)C_2(\Phi) \|\nabla u\|_{L^2(U)}^2
\end{align}
where $C_2(\Phi)=\|\nabla(\Phi^{-1})\|_{C^0(\overline V)}<\infty$ because $\Phi$ is a diffeomorphism. As $\Phi$ is invertible, the reverse estimates also hold.

Response to comments- we also show that $V=\Phi(U)$ is compactly contained in $V'$. Recall that $A\Subset B$ for open sets $A,B$ means that there exists a compact set $C$ such that $\overline A\subset C\subset B$. As $\Phi$ is a diffeomorphism, in particular, $\Phi^{-1}$ is continuous, and therefore the images of open/closed sets under $\Phi$ (= preimages under $\Phi^{-1})$ are also open/closed respectively. Also recall that the continuous image of compact sets are also compact.

Hence, to get the result- by assumption, $U\Subset U'$,  i.e. there exists $K$ such that $\overline U\subset K \subset U'$. Applying the map $\Phi$ we obtain $\Phi(\overline U)\subset \Phi(K) \subset \Phi(U')$, i.e. $\overline V \subset \Phi(K) \subset V'$. By the previous paragraph, $V,V'$ are open, and there is a compact set $C=\Phi(K)$ between $ \overline V$ and $V'$; hence $V\Subset V'$.

Comment: What do you mean by reverse estimate?

Comment: your question is about two inequalities; I proved only one, but the other one is 100% analogous.

Comment: Hi @Silver54, is there an issue with this answer? If you are not convinced, I'd be happy to try to improve it. I noticed you haven't accepted the answers to any of your questions. If you are happy with an answer, you should accept the answer to let others know that it has solved your problem. You can do so by clicking on the tick ✔️  on the left of an answer.

Comment: Your answer is fine but I also need an answer to the first part of the question (about open and compactedness). I was not aware of the tick and will certainly click it if you can help out with the first part

Comment: @Silver54 I don’t see a first part of the question. Do you want to prove that $V$ is open and compactly contained in $V’$? This follows immediately because $\Phi^{-1}$ is continuous.

Comment: Yes. Can you please add it to your answer? I will press the tick.

Comment: @Silver54 I have modified the answer

Comment: @Silver54 I see you have unaccepted the answer. what is wrong with it?